# Pyinstaller problems with adding files

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a file called `Ringbell.py` and an mp3 called `bell.mp3`. The former has one line which says:

```
import subprocess    
subprocess.call(['cvlc','bell.mp3'])   I also have one with full paths.
```

When I don't use PyInstaller, this works nicely, when I use PyInstaller first then delete the `bell.mp3` (under the assumption that it has been embedded in the `py.exe` file), it doesn't work. I am using Python 3.6.8 and Linux ubuntu.

```
pyinstaller -F --add-data bell.mp3:. Ringbell.py
```

The above is the command, but the mp3 does not go in the `Ringbell.exe`.

Comment: Your assumption is simply incorrect. The mp3 file still has to be in the same working folder if that's your code (using a subprocess)

Comment: can you please elaborate? do you mean that my problem is a function of subprocess or of the lack of my understanding of pyinstaller????,...I was hoping to put all the mp3 inside the exe....so i can distribute that. ..Is that not possible?..if my problem is due to the use of subprocess, what else can i use ?

Comment: if you really embedded the mp3 file into the executable, then it will be extracted to a temporary directory during startup. look up the doc of pyinstaller and use an absolute path to that directory.
if the work most also work for a non pyinstaller version, then check for the `sys.frozen` attribute in an if statement and use one  or the other path depending on it.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in the comments, the mp3 would be available on your executable but you need to load it from the extracted path (e.g `C:/User/AppData/Local/Temp/_MEIXXX`). You can use [`sys._MEIPASS`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/runtime-information.html#using-file-and-sys-meipass) to retrieve the path of extraction:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import os


def resource_path(relative_path):
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative_path)


subprocess.call(['cvlc', resource_path('bell.mp3')])
```